# How to create a tracking script with js and php?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to create a simple tracking script to give to my clients. Something similar with GA but very basic.

The requirements are

give the clients a single and simple js script like google Analytics does

make most of the logic inside the js file loaded by 3th party sites from the main site

collect in PHP the information and store it

What I can't figure yet is what are the ways to do this?
Google from what I see is loading a gif file, stores the information and parses the logs.
If I do something similar sending the data to a php file Ajax cross site policy will stop me, from what I remember.

So what is a clean way to do this ? ( I don't need code  just the logic behind it )

Comment: Did you consider [PIWIK][1] :-)


  [1]: http://www.piwik.org

Comment: Yes, but it's more then I need. Good tool though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Method a - web bug:**

Give the user this:
`<img src="http://www.yourserver.com/yourtracking.php?associateid=3rdpartyid" width="1" height="1" />`

have the php return `header("content-type:image/gif");` and serve them a gif file for their effort.

**Method b - script**

Create a php file that can parse parameters and have it return `content-type:text/javascript` 
Have them load it like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourserver.com/yourtracking.php?associateid=3rdpartyid"></script>`

If you want to you can do additional stuff like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var associateId = "12345";
  var trackingPage="homepage";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourserver.com/yourtracking.php?associateid=3rdpartyid"></script>
```

then in the php have code like this (watch the nested quotes)

```
$str = 'var url = "http://www.yourserver.com/moretracking.php?associateid="+associateId+';
$str .= '"&page="+trackingPage+"&ref="+escape(document.referrer);\n';
$str .= 'document.write(\'<img src="\'+url+\'"/>\');';

echo $str;
```

Comment: This works ok for me, but I needed to change `document.referrer` to `window.location.href` in the ref, since technically you aren't getting the referrer, you're getting the page href itself.

Comment: Also, if you don't want the image to show up as a blank image, you can add `style="display: none"`

Answer (score 0):

You may read this (found googling) about cross domain ajax and its possible solutions... http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj/

Answer (score 0):

Well, i use some php code that is included in my script that logs Ip Addresses and as much information i can get from a server-side perspective. It saves it in a MySql Database. I also use a Ajax script to post data to a php script, the data in this case is Screen Heigth and thing you only can get client-side.